# PHP: Upload an image with image name prepended by HTTP Path?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have the following php which uploads image to server with name inserted in database:

```
<?php

//Uploading File to server php folder//
$uploaddir = ''; //Uploading to same directory as PHP file

$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

$uploadFile = $file;

$randomNumber = rand(0000, 99999); 

$newName = $uploaddir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
 } 

else {
echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
}


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
$postsize = ini_get('post_max_size'); 
$canupload = ini_get('file_uploads');  
$tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir'); 
$maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
echo "http://localhost/abc/images/{$newName}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] .    "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
}



//Making sql db connection to store image path in db table//

$host = "localhost";

$username = "root";
$password = "****";

$database = "userauth";

mysql_connect($host, $username);

mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to find database");

$image = $_GET["images"];

$qry = "INSERT INTO image VALUES ('','$newName')";

mysql_query($qry);

mysql_close();
    ?>
```

The above code easily uploads files with temporary name: upload_image prepended by random number to the following xampp folder path: http://localhost/abc/images/

In the db table, i rev the image name as 'randomnumber'upload_image.jpg.
What I need is that I need the db table to display image name along with the full path as http://localhost/abc/images/'rand.number'upload_image.jpg

How am I able to achieve this?

I tried to replace uploaddir with "http://localhost/abc/images/" and tried to add it to the new file name but it returned the following warning:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/abc/images/33760upload_image.jpg)   [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: failed to open   stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in    <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/abc/images/imageupload.php</b> on line    <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpdlCc5N' to 'http://localhost/abc/images/33760upload_image.jpg' in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/abc/images/imageupload.php</b> on line   <b>24</b>
<br />
```

Valuable guidance required.

PS: PERMISSIONS ARE SET TO READ AND WRITE
    Table contains two fields: ID and Image with ID set to primary and auto increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

with the `$_SERVER` array you can access some http request details, e.g. the path

you should not try to move the uploaded file from / to an readonly protocol like http. instead just get it from the php tmp directory. also don't start a filename like that while moving it, which causes your errors i think.

Comment: i tried to implement $_Server array but failed miserably. Is there any difference between Xampp and Mamp.. SHould i prefer Mamp over Xampp

Comment: getting the following error: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/abc/images/96818upload_image.jpg) [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/abc/images/imageupload.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file() [<a href='function.move-uploaded-file'>function.move-uploaded-file</a>]: Unable to move '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpcM4Ln7' to 'http://localhost/abc/images/96818upload_image.jpg' in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/abc/images/imageupload.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />

Comment: as i already said the move target is wrong. you need to specify a valid dir on your hdd.

Comment: but upload dir is same as the folder where php file is saved. Please sir, help me out with some code here, I am not an experienced php guy, just another app developer. Please sir

Comment: $newName contains something like http:// at its start, doesn't it? that causes the error so change how $newName = ... is build up.

Comment: i have already discarded that but how would i put the image name with complete http path...plz sir help me here

Comment: just store the image with its name and path at move_uploaded file, use another php variable then to store it e.g. with the full path inside the db.